# edit rows in a matrix, MatLab

Tags: matlab, matrix, rows

I have a matrix `A` and I want to multiply every row by 2 using a `for` loop.

```
A = [1 2 3; 
     4 5 6; 
     7 8 9];
```

So essentially matlab should output:

```
[2  4  6; 
 8  10 12; 
 14 16 18];
```

I tried:

```
A = [1 2 3 ; 4 5 6  ; 7 8 9];
for i=1:3
    x= A([i],:)*2;
end
```

but `x` outputs as `[14 16 18]`.

How can I get my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a for loop that will be:

```
for n=1:size(A,1)
    x(n,:)=2*A(n,:);
end
```

But it is much easier to get the same result without a for loop:

```
x=2*A;
```

Answer (score 0):

In think your answers are getting overwritten every time you go in the for loop. You may be able to do something like this:

```
 for i=1:3
     x([i],:) = A([i],:)*2;
 end
```

Answer (score -1):

For loops are very very inefficient in MAtlab. I would suggest you learn to work around it when using matlab. For something small like this you may not see any detrimental effect, but for anything large scale, it's a no.

Anyway, for your problem, you can just do `x = A*2`. That should give you your solution.

Comment: that's not accurate anymore.  JIT compiler in recent versions of Matlab has improved to the point where loops can be faster than vectorized code. It is difficult to know in advance which will be faster, so the best approach is to write the code in the most natural fashion, profile it and then if there is a bottleneck, try switching from loops to vectorized (or the other way)....  see also http://www.matlabtips.com/matlab-is-no-longer-slow-at-for-loops/

Comment: ah okay, thanks. one more thing, how would i go about doing it if i wanted just column 1 multiplied by 2?

Comment: @natan: Did not know that, that's interesting :)